# Resolve no resource identifier found for attribute 'margin' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm using below layout to populate my fragment. But I'm constantly getting 
No resource identifier found for attribute 'margin' in package 'android' error when I compile and run.

```css
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/rp"
                android:src="@drawable/gradient" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:margin="10px"
                android:elevation="9px"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20px"
                android:textSize="60px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Royal Physicsit of CDP" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:margin="2px"
            >

            <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:margin="10px"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/join"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20px"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Join Us"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:margin="10px"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20px"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Mail Us"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Information"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/royal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It gives me Error constantly and I have no idea how to resolve it.

I look for solution in other thread but coudln't solve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
android:layout_margin="10px"
```

Instead

```
android:margin="10px"
```

Your using wrongly so use attribute layout_margin instead of margin

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/rp"
                    android:src="@drawable/gradient" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10px"
                    android:elevation="9px"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20px"
                    android:textSize="60px"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Royal Physicsit of CDP" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_margin="2px"
                >

                <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_margin="10px"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/join"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20px"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Join Us"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20px"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Mail Us"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Information"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/royal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```